# how to split a word file page wise using C#.NET(3.5)

Tags: c#, ms-word

I want to split a word file containing 1000 pages into 1000 word files with each with single page.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link to a vba snippet to split a word doc based on a delimiter. You should be able to adapt that fairly easily to splitting by pages.

http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=922

FYI, there's tons of great VBA code for manipulating office docs, I googled "split word document VBA" to find that article for instance.